# configure NGINX to work with squid

Tags: nginx, squid

I have squid running on one server(192.168.29.246) with sslbump enabled.

I configured nginx(192.168.29.245) in the other server and i want it to work in front of squid.

However, only the querystring is passed to squid. so for http://www.example.co/xxx.html, only xxx.html is passed to squid.

How to fix this.

Error Message

```
The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: /xxx.html
```

nginx.conf

```
upstream squid {
 server 192.168.29.246:3128;

}

server {
    listen 8338;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
       proxy_pass http://squid;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Comment: As this is how it is supposed to be done, I would suggest you take a look at the documentation as well as your nginx configuration.

Comment: Also nginx is a caching proxy and squid is a caching proxy, you might want to pick just one.

Comment: This question seemed to solved now under this tread: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331813/reverse-proxy-from-nginx-to-squid